# setChecked of switch is not working

Tags: android, uiswitch

I have use a switch in my app to enable and disable notifications. Now I am creating an events.

I want to show switch checked if any notification is set to that event or else it should be false. But I am not getting any change for this. The switch is shown off every time.

When I did debug if notification is not null then it goes to else part but switch dose not show on.

```
 notificationTime = eventData.getNotificationTime();

        if(notificationTime.equals(""))
        {
            notify.setChecked(false);
        }
        else {
            notify.setChecked(true);
        }
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to handle switch in Android.

```
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // do something, the isChecked will be
        // true if the switch is in the On position
    }
});
```

Comment: I know this, but how to show switch on by default if notification is set?

Comment: If i do just setChecked(true) it shows on but not showing in this code.

Comment: can you add `Log.w("check"," "+working);` inside the if loop posted in the code, to see whether the `if` loop is getting executed or not? you should receive the log in logcat if its working!

Comment: If you don't see that in the Logcat, it means there is something wrong with the condition of if loop, do fix it!

Answer (score 0):

To make changes to UI elements specially **switch** element you need to use the seperate thread method.

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run () {
     // update switch, button etc...

     }
}, <Duration>);
```